# Firefox Add-ons toolbar

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How to add a toolbar using firefox add-ons SDK ?

I tried to bring the same effect by adding a widget and attaching a panel to it,but also it does not support floating panels,and also the panel is displayed above scree (hiding the scree content).
I want to display a toolbar with some content in it.

Comment: If you ever give up on the sdk solution and want a non-sdk solution let me know. I do regular bootstrap addons.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [sdk/ui/toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_toolbar)

Example:

```
var { ActionButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var { Toolbar } = require("sdk/ui/toolbar");
var { Frame } = require("sdk/ui/frame");

var previous = ActionButton({
  id: "previous",
  label: "previous",
  icon: "./icons/previous.png"
});

var next = ActionButton({
  id: "next",
  label: "next",
  icon: "./icons/next.png"
});

var play = ActionButton({
  id: "play",
  label: "play",
  icon: "./icons/play.png"
});

var frame = new Frame({
  url: "./frame-player.html"
});

var toolbar = Toolbar({
  title: "Player",
  items: [previous, next, play, frame]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply....But when I am trying this I get the following error,

ModuleNotFoundError: unable to satisfy: require(sdk/ui/button/action) from
  /Downloads/addon-sdk-1.15/toolbar1/lib/main.js:1:

Looked for it in:
  /Downloads/addon-sdk-1.15/toolbar1/lib/sdk/ui/button/action.js
  /Downloads/addon-sdk-1.15/lib/sdk/ui/button/action.js
  /Downloads/addon-sdk-1.15/toolbar1/lib/sdk/ui/button/action.js

Comment: use the latest version, sdk 1.16